# How can I use SQLite for PHPUnit Functional Testing in TYPO3 9LTS

Tags: php, sqlite, phpunit, typo3, functional-testing

Since TYPO3 9.4 [1] there is support for SQLite in TYPO3, This is recommended for small websites, development environments or testing.

But I don't know how to use this in testing context, the MySQL I've used for ages like this `TYPO3_PATH_WEB=$PWD/.Build/Web typo3DatabaseName=database typo3DatabaseHost=localhost typo3DatabaseUsername=root typo3DatabasePassword=root .Build/bin/phpunit -c config.xml Tests/Functional`

I'm looking into this option with the hope of being able to speed up my functional testing, which I currently finds to slow.

1) https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.4/Feature-85256-InstallTYPO3OnSQLite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sqlite on the server or in the docker container where you run your tests and then simply set

```
typo3DatabaseDriver=pdo_sqlite
```

as environment variable in front of your command. That's sufficient to run your tests with sqlite.

I've written an [article](https://medium.com/@wolfgang.klinger/typo3-extension-testing-a1a665bd528b) where I cover this too.

Comment: When I do this i get

```
RuntimeException: The requested database connection named "Default" has not been configured.
```

Looks like i'm still missing something.

Running following command for the TYPO3 Crawler.

```
typo3DatabaseDriver=pdo_sqlite ./.Build/bin/phpunit --bootstrap .Build/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/res/Configuration/FunctionalTestsBootstrap.php Tests/Functional/Domain/Repository/QueueRepositoryTest.php
```

Comment: FYI: I'm testing with the typo3v9 branch of the crawler.